# Is asking users to enrol in SMS 2FA when they already have an authenticator good security practise?

Tags: multi-factor, sms, sim-swapping

I already have an authenticator for Amazon AWS, and I'm being regularly asked to add an SMS 2FA as well.

If I add SMS MFA, will I become vulnerable to sim-swapping attacks on that MFA?

Same thing with many other services, I already have authenticators with them, and they're still asking me to add an SMS 2FA.

Here's the prompt I get, although I already have an authenticator setup:

[image]

Comment: Right, so this is what I thought. They are not ***forcing*** you to enroll in SMS. This defeats the premise to your question. There is no forcing of a reduction of your security. "Remove your number in Login & Security to cancel" to stop getting these messages.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very common approach to add/mantain SMS 2FA as a secondary/backup method. It's not secure, because users are vulnerable to SIM swap attack, but you have to balance security & usability of 2FA.

2FA Apps are not so easy to use/understand for many users. You can use any Authenticar App, but you need to backup the activation code/QRCode, and users have to backup this in some place...so it's easier to maintain SMS 2FA. Otherwise you'll have users lockout from services with request to the support and unsatisfaction and so on.

In conclusion, it's not a good security practice for me, it's only a transient mesure to avoid lock out of users from services. And the availability of a service is one of the three pillars of information security: Confidentiality, Integrity and Availability.

For example, look at these papers on the argument.

- Don't Punish all of us: Measuring User Attitudes about Two-Factor Authentication: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8802493
- Recent Trends in User Authentication - A Survey: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8784263

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this considered a good security practice?

There are legitimate reasons to encourage users to have some kind of backup second factor in they lose their authenticator and need to re-gain access to their account. But I'd question whether it's actually being used as a *security* practice to help protect your account, or whether the company has other reasons for doing it.

Some companies require mobile numbers to make it harder for people to register multiple accounts (see the recent stories about [Overwatch 2](https://www.polygon.com/guides/23380339/overwatch-2-sms-protect-phone-number-required) and [Modern Warfare 2](https://www.theverge.com/2022/10/10/23396412/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-ii-sms-protect-prepaid-postpaid-phone-number-requirement)). Others want to get phone numbers in order to use them for marketing or other purposes - and encouraging or forcing them to use it for authentication can be an effective way to obtain them.